# Take screen screenshot Android api 26

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, screenshot

I'm trying to make a screenshot of an activity in android, I found many examples online, but none works properly.
In my case with a broadcast-receiver I intercept a specific event, and I launch an activity and I need to make the screenshot of this activity?
Does anyone have any advice?

PS. I have already imported all the permissions to be able to save the screens on the disk.
I use android api 26.

code that I found online

```
    try {
        // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
        View view = getWindow().getDecorView();
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap b1 = rootView.getDrawingCache();
        Rect frame = new Rect();
        getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(frame);
        int statusBarHeight = frame.top;

        //Find the screen dimensions to create bitmap in the same size.
        int width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        int height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b1, 0, statusBarHeight, width, height - statusBarHeight);

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // Several error may come out with file handling or DOM
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When the code reaches the line who try to create Bitmap b, return java null point exception, because b1 is null.

Comment: show me some of your code

Comment: I add an example of my code in the question

Comment: What does "none works properly" mean? What are your symptoms? When are you calling the code that is shown in your question?

Comment: this is good code! and works . what is wrong?

Comment: return java null pointer exception, when I try to create Bitmap b

Answer (score 0):

As you're getting NPE creating bitmap I suppose you don't have `rootView` variable . I don't see it initialized , maybe you wanted to put there `view.getDrawingCache();`

Refer this working example of creating bitmap

```
// create bitmap screen capture
        View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-in-android). I think there're nice answers to you question

Comment: Returns java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference, when it try to create Bitmap

Comment: You should debug and see which parameter of createBitmap is null, it could be because your methods  of getting width and  height are deprecated. It could cause a problem too